# CakePHP 3 - Setting data from table to default.ctp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to set data from a table to `default.ctp`. So in `AppController.php`, I added:

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
    $usersTable = TableRegistry::get('Users');
    $users = $usersTable->getAllUsers();

    $this->set('users', $users);
}
```

And in `default.ctp`:

```
<?php
    foreach($users as $user){
    echo '<li class="tree-submenu" id="employees-submenu">' . $user['first_name'] . '</li>';
    }
?>
```

But apparently $users was not set.
I also tried adding this in `PagesController.php` but I got a blank screen after doing so:

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
    {
        parent::beforeFilter($event);
    }
```

I need some help to figure out what I'm missing, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: should work. Maybe the problem is in your getAllUsers() method not returning anything

Answer (score 0):

When I have issues setting variables I just do print_r ($users); and see if anything is displayed, just to be sure.

Odds are it's in the getAllUsers method but it's worth noting your echo statement is wrapped in single quotes and you use single quotes in the variable too. Should try to keep those separate So make it $user["first_name"] instead.

Answer (score 0):

so you are just try to set a data from appcontroller to default.ctp

you did not write in your question the "getAllUsers method"

and so.........You can just display all the record in the users table by this code below

```
public function beforeFilter(\Cake\Event\Event $event)
{
  $usersTable = TableRegistry::get('Users');
  $users = $usersTable->find('all');
  $this->set('data', $users );
}
```

and default.ctp

```
<?php
  foreach($data as $users){
       echo '<li class="tree-submenu" id="employees-submenu">' . 
   $users['first_name']. '</li>';
    }
?>
```

I've try it locally and it will display all the firstname in the table users.